# Runtime issue with 64bit Unity game integration into iOS native app

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, 64-bit

My company integrates Unity games into our native iOS app. Basically our iOS app would run the Unity code when a user decides to launch any of the games.

With the past 32 bit of Unity and native iOS code, we were taking Unity generated Xcode files, and compiling it into a static lib for the native iOS app to use. Whenever the user chooses to launch any of the games, UnityAppController would be loaded, and ran. This worked well for us.

But with the latest 64 bit builds, the same approach would give us a runtime error on app start - specifically when "main.mm" is executed, the app would crash at the "InitializeScriptingBackend()" call in "main.mm". Please see attached screenshot for sample stack trace.

Same issue happens regardless if we are running in debug or release scheme.

We are currently using Unity version 4.6.3p3 for generating the games for iOS, and using Xcode 6.2 for compiling the Unity code to static lib.

Does anyone have any idea why the crash is happening, and how we might get around it? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Is the native app 64-bit?

Comment: Yes, the app is 64-bit native.

Answer (score 0):

Another discussion is happening on official Unity forum:  http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/runtime-issue-with-64bit-unity-game-integration-into-ios-native-app.316796/